# Splitting strings by {} & []

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm sort of new to Java.
I would like to know if there's an easier yet efficient way to implement the following Splitting of String. I've tried with pattern and matcher but doesn't really come out the way I want it.

```
"{1,24,5,[8,5,9],7,[0,1]}"
```

to be split into:

```
1 
24
5
[8,5,9]
7
[0,1]
```

This is a completely wrong code but I'm posting it anyway:

```
    String str = "{1,24,5,[8,5,9],7,[0,1]}";
    str= str.replaceAll("\\{", "");
    str= str.replaceAll("}", "");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    String[] test = new String[10];
   // String[] _test = new String[10];
    int i = 0;
    String[] split = str.split(",");

    while (matcher.find()) {


        test[i] = matcher.group(0);
        String[] split1 = matcher.group(0).split(",");


      // System.out.println(split1[i]);
           for (int j = 0; j < split.length; j++) {
             if(!split[j].equals(test[j])&&((!split[j].contains("\\["))||!split[j].contains("\\]"))){
              System.out.println(split[j]);
             }

        }
        i++;


    }

}
```

With a given String format lets say {a,b,[c,d,e],...} format. I want to enlist all the contents but the ones in the Square brackets are to be denoted as one element ( like an array).

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried already?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Why this title? The OP never said he wanted to split into multidimensional int array, he said he just wants to split the string...

Comment: @BackSlash  ehh.. maybe I read too much into it.  See further edit.

Comment: Can you specify what the format is a little bit more precisely?  For instance, if it's "a `{`/`}` delimited list of comma separated elements, each of which is either a positive integer, or a string delimited by a `[`/`]` pair," then it will not be hard to produce a small parser, or a regular expression whose group matches are the elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     customSplit("{1,24,5,[8,5,9],7,[0,1]}");
  }


  static void customSplit(String str){
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+|\\[.*?\\]");
     Matcher matcher =
           pattern.matcher(str);
     while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
     }
  }
```

Yields the output

```
1
24
5
[8,5,9]
7
[0,1]
```

Comment: Nice solution.  Be aware, @user2516389, though that this won't perform any check that the list as a whole is surrounded by `{`/`}` braces, and that the “nested arrays,” can contain anything.  E.g., for input `"garbarge at beginning 5,[8,foo,5,9],7}}}"` the output is `5`, `[8,foo,5,9]`, `7` (where each is on its own line).  Another example, "{2,3},4,5" produces `2 3 4 5`, and so does `"{2,3}4,5"`.